# Bootstrap carousel wont show images when i run it in django but they load perfectly fine when i use them in a normal HTML file

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

I used this bootstrap code to insert a carousel in my django website homepage , but the local images just wont load , how ever if i use images from web apis like unsplash they load perfectly fine , or if i use this code in a normal html file they load just fine , it just wont run in django

```
    
    
<body>


<div class="container">
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="img1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="img2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="img3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
  </div>


</div>



  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-eMNCOe7tC1doHpGoWe/6oMVemdAVTMs2xqW4mwXrXsW0L84Iytr2wi5v2QjrP/xp"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-cn7l7gDp0eyniUwwAZgrzD06kc/tftFf19TOAs2zVinnD/C7E91j9yyk5//jjpt/"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Django treat static files i.e. images ,css, js not like normal html.  please follow https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/